# List certain files in folder (using Excel 2003)

Tags: excel, vba, file-listing

I am listing all files that follow a certain pattern using this code:

```
Dim strFileName As String, strFileSpec As String
Dim FileList() As String
Dim intFoundFiles as Integer

strFileSpec = archivePath & PatID & "*.csv"
strFileName = Dir(strFileSpec)
Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
    ReDim Preserve FileList(intFoundFiles)
    FileList(intFoundFiles) = strFileName
    intFoundFiles = intFoundFiles + 1
    strFileName = Dir                     
Loop
```

it loads the files corresponding to the file spec into an array which works fine so far.

Problem:
If I have files like `101-20200120.csv` the code finds also others like `10123-20200120.csv` which also comply to the filter. However I need to list only those that have exactly `101` - not the others like `1012345`.

How can I code that?

Comment: What is the value of `PatID`? Presumably it should be `101-`.

Comment: sorry, PatID is actauuly the number before the dash: 101-20200120

Comment: Then add the dash in: `strFileSpec = archivePath & PatID & "-*.csv"`.

Comment: I'll try. Thanks!!

Comment: So is it `101` or the whole `101-20200120` - your comment is unclear.

Comment: *"Excel 2003"*? I highly recommend to upgrade to a more recent version (especially when using macros). Excel 2003 is [out of support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/918) since more then 10 years now.

Comment: sorry for being unclear, just adding the dash works fine! problem solved.

Comment: @PEH Excel 2003 is much faster than later versions and has a nicer menu structure. All is accessible from anywhere. My favourite.

Comment: @AndreasSwart might be, and you you are much quicker infected. It's old and unsafe: [Total number of security vulnerabilities: 51](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-26/product_id-410/version_id-83425/Microsoft-Excel-2003.html) • I send you one Excel file, you open it and your computer is screwed completely. Then think how fast your Excel 2003 still is if you have to set your computer up from scratch and get your backup back.